# get row number in SQL results

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT a.userid, u.name, u.profilePic , 
   SUM(activity_weight) AS totalPoints, 
  (SELECT @rank:=1 +1) AS rank
 FROM activity_entries a 
 INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = a.userid 
 WHERE competitionId = '5216078af3730' 
 GROUP BY a.userid 
 ORDER BY totalPoints DESC
```

So I have this SQL query which works well, I return the `totalPoints` as I want, but I'm also looking to get the rank/row position for each result.

Currently the query above returns rank 2 for each row, obviously not incrementing properly.

Would love some help/advice!

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

`(SELECT @rank:=@rank +1)`

For each row you just added 1 + 1 which will always be 2.

**EDIT:**

You need to initialize the variable :

```
SET @rank=0;
```

you need to execute this query before and using the **same** connection.

```
SELECT
    tmp.userid,
    tmp.name,
    tmp.profilePic,
    tmp.totalPoints,
    (SELECT @rank:=@rank +1) AS rank
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.userid, 
        u.name, 
        u.profilePic , 
        SUM(activity_weight) AS totalPoints
    FROM 
        activity_entries a 
    INNER JOIN users1 u 
        ON u.id = a.userid 
    WHERE 
        competitionId = '5216078af3730' 
    GROUP BY 
        a.userid 
    ORDER BY 
        totalPoints DESC
) as tmp
```

Comment: Hmm, returned NULL for each row.

Comment: then try to initialize it `SET @rank=0;`

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but where in the query would I set it?

Comment: this is a different query... first you execute `SET ...` and after the `SELECT ...` using the same connection

Comment: I'm getting a strange ranking from this, see here: http://i.imgur.com/jT6CFBu.png

Comment: Ah but now I understand why :) Will try your solution.

Comment: Thanks but now the ranks are all 2 again :)

Comment: sorry about that... bad copy paste :) try now and don't forget to initialize rank variable

Comment: That works perfectly, just to show you, I did it like this - look ok to you? :)Thanks! http://imgur.com/TMLJlei